# List View not calling onItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have implemented an abstract class that has a List View like so:

```
public abstract class ExampleListFragment extends ExampleFragment{

    protected ListView _listView;

    public ExampleListFragment () {
        super();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Set Up the Bottom Bar
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        addList();

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    public void addList() {
        _listView = new ListView(getActivity());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tableLayout);

        _listView.setLayoutParams(parms);
        _listView.setClickable(true);
        _listView.setFocusable(true);

        _listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                longListClick(i);
                return true;
            }
        });

        _listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                listClick(i);
            }
        });


        _layout.addView(_listView);

    }

    public abstract void longListClick(int pos);
    public abstract void listClick(int pos);
}
```

I then have a class that inherits from this to implement the abstract methods which should be called when clicking an item in the list

```
 public class TwitterFragment extends ExampleListFragment {

        private TwitterAdapter _adapter;

//...


        @Override
        public void onSelected() {

            _adapter      = new TwitterAdapter(getActivity());

            populateAdapter();

        }

        private void populateAdapter() {


            showLoadingTweets();

            new TwitterGetTimelineTask().execute(username); //fills adapter with Twitter status info...

        }


        @Override
        public void longListClick(int pos) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.format("You have clicked item number: %d",pos),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void listClick(int pos) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.format("You have clicked item number: %d",pos),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();


        }

       //...

        class TwitterGetTimelineTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

          //...
        }
    }
```

However, whenever I click on an Item, it does not appear to even enter onItemClick functions.

Any ideas? help much appreciated.

****EDIT****

As requested, here is the code for my Adapter

```
public class TwitterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<StatusDetails> _statusDetailsArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater _inflater;

    public TwitterAdapter(Context context) {
        _statusDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<StatusDetails>();
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _statusDetailsArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return _statusDetailsArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return _statusDetailsArrayList.get(i).get_id();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusImage);
            holder.text_line1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
            holder.text_line2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusDateText);


            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Bitmap bmp = _statusDetailsArrayList.get(i).get_profile();

        if (bmp == null) {
            holder.img_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_twitter);
        } else {
            holder.img_icon.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        holder.text_line1.setText(_statusDetailsArrayList.get(i).get_text());
        holder.text_line2.setText(_statusDetailsArrayList.get(i).get_date());


        return view;
    }

    public void addStatus(StatusDetails details) {
        _statusDetailsArrayList.add(details);
    }


    public void setStatuses(ArrayList<StatusDetails> details) {
        _statusDetailsArrayList = details;
    }

    public ArrayList<StatusDetails> getEvents() {
        return _statusDetailsArrayList;
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        _statusDetailsArrayList.clear();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img_icon;
        TextView text_line1;
        TextView text_line2;
    }

}
```

And if needed, the XML of the layout of each list

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/statusImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Status"
    android:id="@+id/statusText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/statusImage" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@id/statusText"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/statusDateText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/statusImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/statusImage" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you are actually filling the adapter. Could you post the code for your adapter as that can change the click behavior of a list.

Comment: One possible issue I can see is you have an image button in your row layout. That means if you click the image button your list views click listeners will not be fired. You should add a click listener to the image button if you want that to be clickable.

Comment: Yes, It seems that if I change from an ImageButton to an ImageView it seems to work fine. Good spot.